# gui.openurl not working (no error)

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

The following code is for an escape menu in a  garrys mod server. It's written in lua. I have no idea what the problem could be and I've been working at it for a very long time. There is absolutely no error returned. Here's the full thing:

```
local buttonList = {
    {
        name = "Continue",
        callback = function(panel)
            panel:Remove();
            Atomic.pauseUI = nil;
        end
    },
    {
        name = "Menu",
        callback = function(panel)
            panel:Remove();

            gui.ActivateGameUI();

            Atomic.showDefaultMenu = true;
            Atomic.delayCheck = true;
        end
    },
    --[[
    {
        name = "Settings",
        callback = function(panel)
            //  panel:Remove();
        end
    },
    --]]
    {
        name = "Rules",
        callback = function(panel)
            gui.OpenURL("https://steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/?url=https://facepunch.com")
        end;
    },
    {
        name = "Disconnect",
        callback = function(panel)
            RunConsoleCommand("disconnect");
        end
    }
};
```

Comment: A reply on https://gmod.facepunch.com/f/gmoddev/oadh/Is-gui-OpenURL-suddenly-broken-for-you-Try-this/ is saying that this doesn't work anymore. Only some specific URLs are allowed.

That is probably the issue.

Comment: working again... there is now a shit looking confirmation box